# Convert string in Hive table to array structure

Tags: arrays, hive, type-conversion, hiveql, complex-data-types

I have a source file that needs to be loaded to a Hive table.  Two fields are arrays of store hours and no matter how I try I can't get them to be loaded as array structs.

Source File:

```
1ab345c5f964a520da6z20e3|This Store Name|[{day:1,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:2,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:3,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:4,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:5,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:6,starttime:330,endtime:1260},{day:7,starttime:330,endtime:1260}]|[{startdate:{month:3,day:27},enddate:{month:3,day:27},weeklyhours:[{day:5,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:3,day:28},enddate:{month:3,day:28},weeklyhours:[{day:6,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:3,day:29},enddate:{month:3,day:29},weeklyhours:[{day:7,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:3,day:30},enddate:{month:3,day:30},weeklyhours:[{day:1,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:3,day:31},enddate:{month:3,day:31},weeklyhours:[{day:2,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:1},enddate:{month:4,day:1},weeklyhours:[{day:3,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:2},enddate:{month:4,day:2},weeklyhours:[{day:4,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:3},enddate:{month:4,day:3},weeklyhours:[{day:5,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:4},enddate:{month:4,day:4},weeklyhours:[{day:6,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:5},enddate:{month:4,day:5},weeklyhours:[{day:7,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:6},enddate:{month:4,day:6},weeklyhours:[{day:1,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:7},enddate:{month:4,day:7},weeklyhours:[{day:2,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:8},enddate:{month:4,day:8},weeklyhours:[{day:3,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:9},enddate:{month:4,day:9},weeklyhours:[{day:4,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:10},enddate:{month:4,day:10},weeklyhours:[{day:5,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:11},enddate:{month:4,day:11},weeklyhours:[{day:6,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:12},enddate:{month:4,day:12},weeklyhours:[{day:7,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:13},enddate:{month:4,day:13},weeklyhours:[{day:1,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:14},enddate:{month:4,day:14},weeklyhours:[{day:2,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:15},enddate:{month:4,day:15},weeklyhours:[{day:3,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:16},enddate:{month:4,day:16},weeklyhours:[{day:4,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:17},enddate:{month:4,day:17},weeklyhours:[{day:5,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:18},enddate:{month:4,day:18},weeklyhours:[{day:6,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:19},enddate:{month:4,day:19},weeklyhours:[{day:7,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:20},enddate:{month:4,day:20},weeklyhours:[{day:1,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:21},enddate:{month:4,day:21},weeklyhours:[{day:2,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:22},enddate:{month:4,day:22},weeklyhours:[{day:3,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:23},enddate:{month:4,day:23},weeklyhours:[{day:4,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:24},enddate:{month:4,day:24},weeklyhours:[{day:5,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:25},enddate:{month:4,day:25},weeklyhours:[{day:6,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:26},enddate:{month:4,day:26},weeklyhours:[{day:7,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:27},enddate:{month:4,day:27},weeklyhours:[{day:1,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:28},enddate:{month:4,day:28},weeklyhours:[{day:2,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:29},enddate:{month:4,day:29},weeklyhours:[{day:3,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true},{startdate:{month:4,day:30},enddate:{month:4,day:30},weeklyhours:[{day:4,starttime:0,endtime:1440}],closed:true}]
```

Here's one of the things I've tried.

```
create external table store_hours (venueid string, venuename string, 
hours array<struct<day:int,starttime:int,endtime:int>>, 
seasonal_hours array<struct<startdate:struct<month:int,day:int,year:int>,enddate:struct<month:int,day:int,year:int>,weeklyhours:array<struct<day:int,starttime:int,endtime:int,label:string>>,closed:boolean>>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/path/to/data';
```

select * from store_hours; 
Returns:

```
1ab345c5f964a520da6z20e3    This Store Name [{"day":null,"starttime":1,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":2,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":3,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":4,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":5,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":6,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":7,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":330,"endtime":null},{"day":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":null}]
```

For "hours" the data is mostly null, but some of the data is actually being read and assigned to values, but the assignments are clearly wrong.

The first value of the array for the hours field is "[{day:1,starttime:330,endtime:1260},..." It looks as though the "1" from "day" is being assigned to "starttime".  Then "330" from starttime is being assigned to starttime, but in the second array, not the first.  And endtime doesn't ever look to be assigned anywhere.

The "seasonal_hours" field output is similar where most are null with some values populated in different/wrong positions.

I can't make out how this is really being executed and loaded and I'm clearly missing something.  I appreciate any help.